# "May" meaning in biblical/religious language

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, ambiguity

I have learned that in the biblical language, in religion or for prayer "may" is used to express a wishful benediction. As in the following examples:

> 1. **May** God bless you.
> 2. **May** your children always be healthy and happy.

But my problem is with the following case:

> 3. "Let me alone, then, that my wrath **may** blaze up against them to consume them. Then I will make of you a great nation." (Exodus 32, 10)

What is the meaning of "*may*" in this last example (example 3)? possibility?

Also, I wonder if "*let me alone*" in this context means "I don't want company" or "Stop bothering me".

Answer (score 18, accepted):

First, a note on "biblical language." Feel free to skip ahead to the answer, below the horizontal rule.

Let's be careful when we talk about "biblical language." The *Tanakh* (the Hebrew Bible) was originally written in Biblical Hebrew and Biblical Aramaic. The Christian New Testament was probably originally written in Koine Greek. These texts have been translated into many other languages, and there are even many different English translations. The most famous English translation is the *King James Version*.  This translation was written in the very beginning of the 1600s in style that was somewhat old fashioned, even for the time.

Many English speakers strongly associate this somewhat-old-fashioned 1600s English with the Bible. But there is nothing particularly biblical about the language. It was more formal than the language typically used by people in England in the 1600s, but it was not meant to sound so alien as it does today.

---

Like most words, *may* has multiple uses.

> **may** auxiliary verb
>
> **3** — used in auxiliary function to express a wish or desire especially in prayer, imprecation, or benediction
>   // *may* the best man win

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/may

You'll notice that the example given has an entirely unreligious context. It's the sort of thing you'd say at the beginning of a hot dog eating contest, for example.

It is true that prayers often come in the form "May something good happen...", but not every sentence like this is a prayer.  In addition to the sporting example, they're often toasts: "may you live a long and healthy life."

Another use of *may* is

> **1 c** *archaic* : have the ability to

That's the meaning of *may* in your third example. In contemporary English, we might write this, "Leave me alone, then, so that my wrath ***can*** blaze up against them to consume them."

Notice, in this definition, that the word is marked as *archaic*<sup>1</sup> (which means it's no longer commonly used). This use of *may* is also often found in religious contexts, but that's really just because many translations of the Bible use older forms of English.  You can find this same usage of *may* in completely secular contexts, like this [*Sportsman's Dictionary*](https://books.google.com/books?id=tKUTAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP136&dq=%22that+he+may%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwi4z_7VsbnoAhVkGDQIHSU2D9o4KBDoATAEegQIAhAC#v=onepage&q=%22that%20he%20may%22&f=false) from 1800:

> You need not be afraid of his having a great belly, provided it be not cow-bellied, which will make him appear deformed; he should have full, but not broad flanks, *that he **may** not sway in the back at his labour.*
>
> ---

1 In the comments, it's been pointed out that this use of *may* is not archaic in all dialects of English. It definitely sounds old-fashioned in Standard American English, but may be appropriate in some British dialects.

Comment: Welll ... if he's reading the King James or one of the other old translations, the English of the time MAY be different from modern English. People often say "Biblical English" to mean "the English language as it was written when the King James version was produced".

Comment: @jay I second that.

Comment: `1 c archaic : have the ability to` - I would argue that `may` in that sense is far from archaic in British English, especially in formal usage. Having said that, of course, I am very, very old myself, so perhaps not the best possible arbiter of the usages of "archaic".

Comment: @Jay What's interesting specifically about the King James and the English "of the time" is that the King James translators _intentionally_ used words and phrases that were [already considered archaic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_James_Version#Style_and_criticism), because they thought it sounded more dignified.

Comment: IIRC some of the oldest extant copies of parts of the Bible are also in archaic Greek so that would be a third "Biblical language".

Comment: @TheAtomicOption, depending on what you consider to be the Bible.  I was intentionally being a little provocative, by using "the Bible" to mean what's often called the "Hebrew Bible," or more insultingly, "The Old Testament."  If we're including the Christian Bible ;), we'd include Koine Greek in that list of "biblical languages."  Anyway, I'd prefer this answer to be informative, rather than controversial, so I'll edit the preface.

Comment: @Juhasz I wasn't aware that those terms were considered insulting by anyone as it's the common usage among Christians I know and decidedly not used with insulting intent by them. And I thought the Jewish common term was Torah rather than Hebrew Bible. Either way, it seems clear that the book inferred from "The Bible" is going to be different depending on the background of the person hearing the phrase. But given that ambiguity, I wouldn't expect it to be controversial to have a complete list of all the languages in any text that at least some people consider part of the document.

Comment: Answer might be improved further by mentioning the subjunctive; "may X" as expressing a desire is one of the few current uses remaining in English.

Comment: @TheAtomicOption, I'm sure that most people who say "Old Testament" do so because of convention, rather than out of an intention to imply that it's been superseded by the New Testament. That is, I'm sure they don't mean to be insulting. Still, I think it's worth pointing out the benefits of more neutrally descriptive language. I've updated my answer, hopefully in a way that requires less guessing at my intent. As for *Torah* vs *Hebrew Bible*, the Torah only refers to the first five books of the Bible.  It's the T in *Tanakh*, which also includes Prophets (*Nevi'im*) and Writings (*Ketubim*)

Comment: To some, hot dog eating is a religious experience.

Comment: I also was not aware that anyone might take offense to "Old Testament".  It was always my assumption that the name was simply based on the fact that it was written at an earlier point in time (and is thus chronologically older) than the chronologically more recent "New Testament".  These terms seem pretty neutral to me, and I've never encountered any reason to assume that "old" or "new" in the name is supposed to have anything to do with one superseding the other (and I don't believe I've ever met any Christians who espoused that view, really)..

Comment: Merriam-Webster labels words/senses as "archaic" not if they're "no longer in use," but rather used infrequently or only in specialized contexts.  A word/sense that is truly no longer in use will be labelled "obsolete."

Comment: Thanks @KevinTroy.  That's useful.

Comment: @Foogod, that the New Testament supersedes the Old Testament is widespread Christian doctrine (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supersessionism). But I'll humbly soften my stance. The use of "Old Testament" may not be insulting, but it is (often unconsciously) Christian, rather than neutral, language. Yes, the New Testament is newer than the Old Testament, but it's older than the Book of Mormon, for instance. Yet a mainline Christian would not call the New Testament, "the newer, but not newest testament" because of this. But I'm not trying to be prescriptive; use whatever language you want.

Comment: @Juhasz Well, but as a Christian I don't use the term "New Testament" as an intentional insult to Mormons, either. I think I can neutrally refer to the Old Testament, the New Testament, the Book of Mormon, the Koran, etc. I'd be interested to hear if any Jews find the term "Old Testament" offensive. Sure, I think Jewish people generally refer to that document as "the Tanakh" or "the Torah". (And I think there's a well known double meaning there: Torah can means the books of Moses, or it can mean the entire Hebrew Bible.) ...

Comment: I don't see why it would be any more insulting to Jews to call the Christian scriptures the "New Testament" then it would be insulting to someone from York in England to refer to the city in America as "New York". But what offends people is often not susceptible to logical analysis.

Comment: @Jay, I don't feel that I can adequately express my point - which is meant to be about neutrality and precision, not about insult and offense - with these comment constraints. But if you're curious, the "Terminology" section of this Wikipedia article is a good start: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hebrew_Bible#Terminology

Comment: @Jay See [Is the title: “New” Testament offensive to Jews? Alternative neutral name?](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/73806/5441)

Comment: @CJDennis Thanks. I just read that.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't really an issue of "Bible English" versus "modern English" or "religious language" versus "secular language", but simply that the word "may" has multiple definitions. You can find the same issue you're talking about in everyday writing today.

The word "may" can be an expression of hopeful intent. Like, "May you find happiness in your marriage".

But it can also mean that a person might or might not do something or that an event might or might not happen. Like, "If you ask Bob, he may be willing to help you".

Following on that meaning, "may" can be used as a warning of a possibility. Like, "If you smoke too much, you may get lung cancer", or, "If you do that again, I may not be so forgiving next time."

The first meaning is what is intended in "May God bless you." The third meaning is intended in, "My wrath may blaze up against them."

Comment: I actually disagree about "my wrath may blaze up".  I believe that "may" here is in the sense of "will be able to" or "will be allowed to".  That is, "if you let me alone, that will make it possible for my wrath to blaze up against them".

Answer (score 2):

‘May’ is often used in religious language as a wishful benediction, but — as you have seen — not always. The usage of ‘may’ is more like an indicator of ‘I want this to happen’. So the sentences would become ‘I want God to bless you’ and ‘I want your children to always be healthy and happy’, and lastly ‘I want my wrath to blaze up against them to consume them’.

As to ‘let me alone’, it does mean something akin to ‘stop bothering me’ or ‘go away’.

Answer (score 0):

'May' in this context could be replaced with 'might' in contemporary English. E.g., "Let me alone, then, that my wrath may blaze up...," could be written as, "Leave me alone, then, so that my wrath might blaze up..."